# Comparing different date formats using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scripting

I am having issues in comparing date formats:
05/31/2017 10:50 AM (IST) and 20170531 003837.000(EST) using Date.parse. Any leads on this?.

```
//Capture input for debug
var Outlmd = "05/31/2017 10:50 AM";
var Outlsr = "20170531 003837.000";
//Convert to internal format - milliseconds since epoch
d1 = Date.parse(05/31/2017 10:50 AM);
d2 = Date.parse(20170531 003837.000);

if(d1 > d2) { NewTempDate = lmd; } else { NewTempDate = lsr; }
```

Comment: //Capture input for debug
var Outlmd = "05/31/2017 10:50 AM";
var Outlsr = "20170531 003837.000";
 
//Convert to internal format - milliseconds since epoch
d1 = Date.parse(05/31/2017 10:50 AM);
d2 = Date.parse(20170531 003837.000);
 
if(d1 > d2) {
    NewTempDate = lmd;
} else {
    NewTempDate = lsr;

Comment: What are the issues you are facing? Add the code in your question not as a comment

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Hi Phil I want to pass the dates as arguments as follows:          
              //Capture input for debug
var lmd = "05/31/2017 10:50 AM";
var lsr = "20170531 003837.000";
 
//Convert to internal format - milliseconds since epoch
d1 = Date.parse(lmd);
d2 = Date.parse(lsr);
 
if(d1 > d2) {
    NewTempDate = lmd;
} else {
    NewTempDate = lsr;
}

Comment: Hi Colwin, Phil....Here is the code:                                                                      //Capture input for debug
var lmd = "05/31/2017 10:50 AM";
var lsr = " 2017-05-31T00:45:25-0400";
 
//Convert to internal format - milliseconds since epoch
d1 = Date.parse(05/31/2017 10:50 AM);
d2 = Date.parse(20170531 003837.000);
 
if(d1 > d2) {
    NewTempDate = lmd;
} else {
    NewTempDate = lsr;
}

Comment: code belongs in the question

Comment: Rob What would be the valid code to compare the above formats then

Answer (score -1):

You forgot quotes within Date.parse

Do `Date.parse('05/31/2017 10:50 AM')`

**Update**
Please consider the code below:

```
//Capture input for debug
var lmd = "05/31/2017 10:50 AM";
var lsr = "2017-05-31T00:45:25-0400";
//Convert to internal format - milliseconds since epoch
d1 = Date.parse(lmd);
d2 = Date.parse(lsr);
if(d1 > d2) { NewTempDate = lmd; } else { NewTempDate = lsr; }
```

Please note that lmd and lsr should be parsable data string without extra spaces: "2017-05-31T00:45:25-0400" not " 2017-05-31T00:45:25-0400"

Comment: //Capture input for debug
var Outlmd = "05/31/2017 10:50 AM";
var Outlsr = "20170531 003837.000";
 
//Convert to internal format - milliseconds since epoch
d1 = Date.parse(05/31/2017 10:50 AM);
d2 = Date.parse(20170531 003837.000);
 
if(d1 > d2) {
    NewTempDate = lmd;
} else {
    NewTempDate = lsr;
}

Comment: Hi Kosh I want to pass the dates as arguments as follows:          
              //Capture input for debug
var lmd = "05/31/2017 10:50 AM";
var lsr = "20170531 003837.000";
 
//Convert to internal format - milliseconds since epoch
d1 = Date.parse(lmd);
d2 = Date.parse(lsr);
 
if(d1 > d2) {
    NewTempDate = lmd;
} else {
    NewTempDate = lsr;
}

Comment: That's OK. But `20170531 003837.000` is not a valid date format. It's not parsable.

Comment: How about  2017-05-31T00:45:25-0400??

Comment: How about  2017-05-31T00:45:25-0400?

Comment: 2017-05-31T00:45:25-0400 is parsable

Comment: see update in my answer

Comment: You should not depend on *Date.parse* to parse non-standard strings. Even standards compliant strings are not parsed correctly by browsers in use.

Comment: but kosh  I am not able to compare the above 2 formats

Comment: `surya amala Vungarala` what do you mean?

Comment: It does not result in valid results when compared after date parsing.Could you suggest the valid code

Comment: so which results are valid?